# a.e. differentiable + continuous implies sobolev function?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $f\in C^0(\Omega)$ (where $\Omega$ is a bounded Lipschitz domain in $\mathbb R^n$).
Suppose that $f$ is almost everywhere differentiable (in the classical sense).
Is this condition sufficient to deduce that $f$ belongs to $W^{1,1}(\Omega)$?

Comment: Maybe $f$ and it's derivative is not integrable?

Comment: I added the condition "bounded" domain.

Comment: Even with this condition you can have $f\notin L^1(\Omega)$, because $\Omega$ is not compact. Moreover, you can also have $f'$ not integrable.

Comment: I agree, sorry for my mistake. I think I should have asked if (in the hypothesis $f$ measurable) I can deduce that $\nabla f$ is measurable (and then, in practice, check if $\|\nabla f\|_{L^1}<\infty$). But this is also answered negatively by Ahriman..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual [Cantor devil's staircase function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function) is a continuous function on $[0,1]$, which is differentiable with $0$ derivative almost everywhere, whereas its derivative in the sense of distributions is a singular measure.